# Microsoft Graph(German cloud) - Get root site (sites/root)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

When making a call to the Microsoft German Graph /sites/root endpoint, it returns 'Resource Not Found', although that in global Graph the same endpoint works perfectly ok

Here is an example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/sites/root
```

It returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'sites'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "aff4a613-54ed-476d-976f-d4ac7a8c7ee2",
      "date": "2018-04-26T07:59:17"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, for now, this service is deployed only in the "beta" API
So I used https://graph.microsoft.de/beta/sites/root and it works